# doubly-linked list confusion

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

In my class I have an assignment to create a Number class, which has operations for arithmetic. (Add/subtract/multiply/etc.)

There is one part I am confused about - the doubly-linked lists. The only part of the spec that discusses it I find a little confusing. I don't know what I'm supposed to be storing - all numbers entered? It says high points to the high-order digit's node...I don't know what that means. Also, I'm not sure exactly how I would implement the doubly-linked list...just have a reference to the next 'high-order digit'?

ALSO - What is `Node`? The assignment only says I am to create the `class Number`...but Node in the Java API says it is something to do with HTML tags? Shouldn't I use `Number low, high`???

Here is the part of the spec detailing the doubly-linked list part:

> Numbers will be stored in doubly-linked lists (do not use generics here). Each node will 
>   have an int value field which will hold one digit (0 through 9) and two pointer fields, 
>   prev and next.
>
> ```
> The Number class will have five fields: 
>
> private Node low, high;
> private int digitCount = 0;
> private int decimalPlaces = 0;
> private boolean negative = false;
> ```
>
> high points to the high-order digit's node, low points to the
>   low-order digit's node, 
>       digitCount is the number of digits stored in the list,
>   decimalPlaces is the number of digits (nodes) 
>       after the decimal place and negative gives the sign.

I am not asking for an exact solution, just some guidance and understanding. I truly appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Node in this context is an element of your linked list.

It seems like you are supposed to represent a Number as a linked list, where each Node contains one digit..

So the number

12.34

will have 4 nodes in it, one for each of 1, 2, 3, and 4.  Your Number will have digitCount of 2 and decimalPlaces of 2 since there are 2 digits each before and after the decimal.

Your linked list should look like

`1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4`

where `<->` represents the doubly linked nature of the linked list (pointers for both previous and next node.)  There should probably be pointers from 1 <-> 4 as well, if the list is supposed to be circular.

The outline of your Number class would look like

```
public class MyNumber {
   DigitNode low;
   DigitNode high;
   int digitCount;
   int decimalPlaces;
   bool negative;
}
```

your DigitNode class outline would look like

```
public class DigitNode {
   int digit;
   DigitNode next;
   DigitNode prev;
}
```

im ignoring things like private/protected and things like setters/getters.  You can now do something like iterate over the digits by getting the `low` property, getting its 'next' property, and looping until `next` is null.

Comment: So am I supposed to implement a Node class? or Node should actually be a reference to Number?

Comment: @doctor, i updated with code outline.  This will get you started, but you still have to do the hard stuff.  You `Number` *class* uses a linked list to represent its digits, each digit being in a `Node`

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how I would keep track of the decimal point?

Comment: @doctor, since you have the `decimalPlaces` variable, you know where to put it already.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a digit is a node, based on this text from your spec:

```
...the number of digits (nodes) after the...
```

High-order, in this context, seems to mean the next power of 10, so the next larger digit, and low order seems to be the opposite, so the next lowest digit.